# How do I know where an email form is being delivered?

Tags: web, web-scraping

Is there a way to extract the email address an online form will send to?

This website for instance: http://www.extrememicro.net
There is a "contact us" page where you fill out first name, last name, subject, and body of a message to this company.

How do I know the email address where this message will be sent to?

Comment: You normally cannot as using a form and backend (server) technology is used to hide the final email address. This is now form the early time of Internet as before there was just a `mailto:contact.us@spamme.company.com` and people using bot to send millions of email to them...

Comment: And this form should also use a anti-bot technology (e.g. captcha) otherwise  it is so easy for a bot to submit plenty of instance of the same form. The web page you mention uses a Captcha.

Answer (score 0):

With the `<form action=""` from the source :

```
 <form action="/#wpcf7-f37-o1" method="post" >
```

So it's a `POST` to the page http://www.extrememicro.net/#wpcf7-f37-o1